# How to insert logs between the method body or in catch block using Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, interceptor

I am using Spring 4 and I don't want to write logger for every single DAO method, instead I want to write an aspect or Interceptor which can intercept each dao methods and put logs in method body and inside catch block. What is correct way of doing this? How can I achieve that?

I tried writing Spring-Advice but I am not able to put logger inside catch block or inside the method.

**My issue is how to write the code so that logger could be put inside each Dao method's body also in catch block of same method's, if any error comes**

This is my Dao class method where I am not Writing any logs

```
      public Person xyz(SomeObject model) {
                Myresponse response=new Myresponse();
                try {
                    DemoClass blocking=new DemoClass(jdtmp);
                    blocking.setlmfuncparam1(model.getCode());
                    blocking.setlmfuncparam2(model.getIdentification());
                    blocking.startaction();
                    return response;
                }catch(BusinessValidationException e)
                {
                    response.setErrorCode(e.getErrorCode());
                    response.setErrorDescription(e.getErrorMessage());
                    response.setSuccess(false);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                            throw new InternalServiceException(APIConstants.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR_CODE,
                            APIConstants.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR_REQUEST_UNABLE_TO_PROCESS);
                }
                return response;
            }
```

I want to write AOP or Interceptor by which every methods written like above will have Loggers like below

```
   <code>
        public Person xyz(SomeObject model) {
            **FILE_LOGGER.debug("In MyDaoImpl Class - xyz method");**
                Myresponse response=new Myresponse();
                try {
                    DemoClass blocking=new DemoClass(jdtmp);
                    blocking.setlmfuncparam1(model.getCode());
                    blocking.setlmfuncparam2(model.getIdentification());
                    blocking.startaction();
                    return response;
                }catch(BusinessValidationException e)
                {
                    response.setErrorCode(e.getErrorCode());
                    response.setErrorDescription(e.getErrorMessage());
                    response.setSuccess(false);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    **FILE_LOGGER.error(Util.getStackTraceAsString(e));**
                    throw new InternalServiceException(APIConstants.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR_CODE,
                            APIConstants.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR_REQUEST_UNABLE_TO_PROCESS);
                }
                return response;
            }
```

Comment: Right way is by writing Aspect which are doing, can you share your code, so that i can see any issues in it...

Comment: @Yogi I have added the code and actual issue

Comment: Check my response as Answer

Comment: Your problem description is unclear. The code you are showing does not explain what you want, only what you have. So if what you have is not what you want, please provide an example explaining what you seem to be unable to express in words, such as a method without logging and then the same again with logging in all the places where you like to have it. Then I can tell you if it is possible with AOP and if so how to do it.

Comment: @kriegaex Hi, I have updated the problem with code blocks as before and after(expected) scenario. Please suggest if  I can archive the same?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem small change i would recommend for catch would be like :

```
@Aspect
@Slf4j
@Component
public class LoggerAspect {

    @Around("execution(* com.foo.bar.api.ws.dao..*.*(..))")
    public Object printServiceLogger(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
        stopWatch.start(proceedingJoinPoint.toShortString());
        String throwableName = null;
        try {
            // execute the profiled method
            return proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            throwableName = throwable.getClass().getName();
            throw throwable;
        } finally {
            stopWatch.stop();
            if (throwableName != null) {
                log.error("ERROR while processing request " + proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature().toString() + " " + +stopWatch.getTotalTimeMillis()
                        + " milliseconds with exception [" + throwableName + "]");
            } else {
                log.debug("Total taken for processing request " + proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature().toString() + " " + +stopWatch.getTotalTimeMillis()
                        + " milliseconds");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And you can also use ***Afterthrowing*** too

Comment: Hi, I have updated the problem with code blocks as before and after(expected) scenario. Please suggest if  I can archive the same?

Answer (score 0):

The first logger statement in you sample code could be replaced by a simple `@Before("execution(* *(..))")` advice in Spring AOP. Of course you should narrow down the pointcut from intercepting all methods to only the ones you are interested in, similar to *Yogi*'s example. But as you neither explain what your DAO classes have in common (package name, class name pattern, implemented interface or base class) nor show any package or class names in your code, I cannot give you a more concrete example now. (If you ask unclear questions on SO, you can only get somewhat unclear answers, sorry.)

The problem is the second log statement inside the `catch` block. In AspectJ you could use a `handler()` pointcut, but Spring AOP [does not support it](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-pointcuts-designators). So if you really want this, you need to [activate full AspectJ via LTW (load-time weaving)](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-using-aspectj) within Spring.

A workaround would be not to intercept the catch block itself but the thrown `InternalServiceException` via an `@AfterThrowing` advice. The downside of this solution is your unorthodox way of exception handling: You instantiate the new exception but do not give it the original one as a cause in the constructor. You just swallow the original exception, making debugging unnecessarily difficult. This is a bad way of exception handling. So from the `@AfterThrowing` advice you cannot log the original exception anymore in this case.

Bottom line: refactor or switch to AspectJ.

P.S.: Feel free to add more details to your question, then I can provide a concrete aspect code sample.